# How to send information to database without reloading page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, database, mysqli

so, i´m trying to send some information to database with AJAX/PHP but without success, i´ve seen some codes from here but they are not working and I just get this error
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

HTML

```
<form action="javascript:void;" id="putz" class="putz" method="POST" onsubmit="send()" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
              <div class="box">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
                <label>Name</label>
              </div>
              <div class="box">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
                <label>Email</label>
              </div>
              <div class="box">
                <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" required>
                <label>Password</label>
              </div>
              <div class="Box">
                <p style="color: red; text-align: left; margin-left: 15px">Photo</p>
                <input type="file" name="photo" style="margin-right: 140px; color: red;">
              </div>
              <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

And here is my ajax/javascript

```
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function send()
{
 var name=document.getElementById( "name" );
 var email=document.getElementById( "email" );
 var pass=document.getElementById( "pass" );
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'send.php',
    data: {
      name:name,
      email:email,
      pass:pass,
    },
  });
}       
    </script>
```

and the send.php code

```
 <?php 
    include_once('conn.php');
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $photo = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "img/foto_perfil/" . $photo);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (name, email, photo, pass) VALUES ('$name', '$email','$photo', '$pass')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $
```

Comment: So, what does happen? Have you looked at your developer's tools console to see if there are errors? Are you testing this over HTTP/HTTPS and not the file system? Did you look at the developer's tools network tab to confirm communication?

Comment: Open your browser console. If you see any errors please read them and if you don't understand them please include them into your question. My guess would be that you haven't included the `jQuery Library`. Also I think your `data` object should only end with `}` not `},` but not 100% sure. Just noticed it.

Comment: Yeah I get this error 
TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Comment: You don't have the JQuery library loaded. You must reference it by adding this to your code prior to calling `$.ajax()`   - - `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Now I just get this error
TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.

Comment: Well, you haven't included all your relevant code then because `stepUp` is not present in what you've posted. Now, it's likely you have a different problem somewhere else.

Comment: I dont have any 'stepUp', and the line error just says that is in the $.ajax() one

Comment: This may not be the issue, but you should never give an element a `name` or and `id` of `name` as it can create conflicts with the Global `name` property of the `window` object. I would also never create a JavaScript variable called `name` for the same reason. Change your naming of those things and try again.

Comment: You also have some typos, remove the comma after  `pass:pass,` and the comma on the next line: `},`

Comment: Now i´m getting a new error
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at HTMLInputElement.toString (<anonymous>)
    at x (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at jt (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You didn't have the JQuery library referenced prior to your
  invocation of `$.ajax()`.
- You are referring to the actual HTML Elements as the data to pass
  when you should be passing the values of those elements.
- You also have trailing commas after the last key/value pair in your
  `data` object and after the `data` key itself.
- I would also rename any/everything that you named `name` as this can
  cause conflicts with the Global `window.name` property.
- (FYI) You aren't using the `label` element correctly. You either wrap
  it around the form element that it is a label for or you give it a
  `for` attribute with a value of the `id` of the form element that it
  is a label for.

---

```js
function send() {
  // Get the values of the elements, not the elements themselves:
  var userName = document.getElementById( "userName" ).value;
  var email = document.getElementById( "email" ).value;
  var pass = document.getElementById( "pass" ).value;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'send.php',
    data: {
      userName: userName,
      email: email,
      pass: pass
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="putz" class="putz" 
      method="POST" onsubmit="send()" enctype="multipart/form-data" > 
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" required>
    <label for="userName">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" required>
    <label for="pass">Password</label>
  </div>
  <div class="Box">
    <p style="color: red; text-align: left; margin-left: 15px">Photo</p>
    <input type="file" name="photo" style="margin-right: 140px; color: red;">
  </div>
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Its appearing this error now :  
SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script

Comment: @JoãoGabriel Look at the line number of the error and click on it to be taken to that line and tell us what the line is.

Comment: It says that is line 1, but line 1 is the <html>

Comment: @JoãoGabriel So you have a syntax error somewhere in your script. There's not much more we can tell you, but the AJAX part is now correct.